# Как устроена база данных например mysql?

Tags: c++, mysql, база-данных, postgresql, архитектура

Я так понимаю есть файл базы к примеру test.db

В test.db есть pages(страницы - я так понимаю это набор битов, разделение для быстрого доступа) по 8кб(допустим). Если файл базы огромный, как база быстро переключается на нужную страницу (на нужную область памяти).

К примеру есть текстовый файл с 1 миллион строк. Как мне быстро переключатся на нужную строку? к примеру сейчас я на 10 строке, оп уже на 200 тысячной и т.д.. без цикла? То есть как организован данный функционал для быстрого переключения на нужную страницу в базе? (или на строку в файле? если такое возможно)

Надеюсь поймете что я имею ввиду!

Comment: Если страницы по 8кб, то можно например использовать формулу page * 8kb для быстрого перехода к нужной странице

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ну вот я не пойму как курсор перемещать в файле, если загрузить байты в ОЗУ то да, а как по файлу перемещаются? Если файл весит 10 Гб то ОЗУ может не хватить.... как перемещаться в  файле...

Comment: @user3737786 а, ну это просто, какой нибудь функцией `fseek` (в зависимости от вашего языка/платформы). И в итоге (упрощенно) головка жесткого диска быстро на нужной сектор перемещается.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian на сколько я знаю функция seek добирается до нужной строчки циклом или я не прав?

Comment: @user3737786 скорей всего `seek` обратиться к операционной системе, та к драйверу диска, а он в курсе как быстро на нужный кусок передвинуть головку по смещению (утрировано, но суть примерно такова)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian да действительно смещает(в документации глянул), а я думал циклом и не смотрел(может не до понял, инглиш йопт). спасибо за наведение моего курсора!

Comment: Быстрый поиск в БД осуществляется с помощью [индексов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Индекс_(базы_данных)).

Comment: Если у вас файл текстовый, то видимо подразумевается разная длина строк. тогда вам точно не обойтись без некой дополнительной структуры в которой будут хранится как минимум адреса начала строк в файле. или например номера строк с которых начинается очередная страница.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу в общих чертах описать как базы хранит в файлах PostgreSQL.

Постгрес хранит таблицы и индексы в отдельных файлах. Максимальный размер файла = 1GB (также называется сегментом), если таблица/индекс выходит за эти пределы, то она дробится на несколько файлов по 1GB. В сегментах размещаются странички размером по 8kB (эта цифра, как и ограничение в 1GB может меняться на этапе компиляции). При работе с данными эти странички выгружаются в память и при необходимости повторного чтения берутся уже оттуда.

Непосредственно строки (`tuples` в терминологии постгреса) хранятся в этих страничках следующим образом:

В начале каждой странички имеется заголовок. Из интересного для нас на данный момент там хранится указатель на начало свободного места в страниче и указатель на его окончание. После загловка лежат идентификаторы строк, хранящихся в страничке. Каждый идентификатор представляет из себя указатель на начало строки и её размер. Постгрес наделяет каждую строку в базе уникальным идентификатором (CTID), он как раз и состоит из номера странички + идентификатора строки в ней. Это позволяет, имея CTID, быстро и без проблем найти строку на диске.

Сами данные заполняют страничку с конца. Это позволяет уменьшить фрагментацию страничек и более рационально упаковывать в них строки.

Вот приблизительное графическое представление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Если очень сжато и опуская многочисленные детали, то по данным MySQL вы передвигаетесь при помощи адресной арифметики, т.е. вы всегда можете очень быстро вычислить в какой области памяти находится та или иная запись. Достигается это следующим образом.

Все данные фиксированной длины вроде `INT`, `FLOAT` размещаются прямо в структуре записи. Плюс в записи имеется динамический участок, длиной 65536 байт в котором размещаются данные не фиксированной длины вроде `VARCHAR`, здесь же хранятся NULL-значения. Если вы создадите несколько столбцов `VARCHAR`, которые полностью выберут этот динамический участок в 65536 байт, MySQL вам просто не даст создавать новые столбцы (Попробуйте ради интереса создать UTF-8 VARCHAR длиной 65536 - под  UTF8-символ в MySQL отводится либо 3, либо 4 байта, в зависимости от кодировки). Тяжелая артиллерия вроде `BLOB`, `TEXT` полей хранится вообще отдельно. Поэтому вы всегда можете вычислить адрес вашей записи, просто маппите данные в память, знаете где начало участка памяти, а адрес любой строки можете вычислить зная размер фиксированного участка. В нем же хранится адрес динамического участка и `BLOB/TEXT`-значений.

Есть отличная книга "MySQL. Оптимизация производительности.  Бэрон Шварц, Петр Зайцев, Вадим Ткаченко, Джереми Д. Зооднай, Дерек Дж. Баллинг, Арьен Ленц". Переведена на русский язык и является отличным введением в архитектуру MySQL.

Comment: Вы бы написали для таблиц какого формата это написали. Потому как написанное смахивает на несжатый формат хранения MyISAM. И абсолютно не подходит для сжатого и тем более innoDB

Comment: @Mike Вообще MySQL состоит из ядра и подключаемых движков таблиц - это не типично для баз данных, поэтому я описал базовые типы, которые в ядре - там они так и реализованы. В InnoDB дерево - не возьмусь его описывать, InnoDB сложен и не думаю, что автору, если он задумал написать простенькую СУБД следует на нее ориентироваться. Я бы не стал.